# Troubleshooting Folder Creation based on User Input in Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a simple batch file that based on comma delimited input would create a series of nested folders.  In the following code, **GSD** is the master folder where everything will live. From there the user would enter differing blocks separated by commas. This could be A,B,C or Z,G,I and so on.

Based on that input the batch file should create block specific folders and nest everything appropriately. The code I have functions perfectly when the user only enters one block (i.e. A), but it falls apart and I get Access Denied errors when I try to run it with inputs of more than one block (i.e. A,B,C).  Any help would be greatly appreciated as my coding knowledge is next to none.

I am trying to nest block folders within the other folders and then all folders under GSD.

```
@echo off

rem Get User Input
set /p gsd= Enter the GSD of the project: 
set /p blocks= Enter the blocks you are prepping a drive for separated by commas (i.e. A,B,C,etc.): 
set ItemCount=0

mkdir %gsd%

mkdir 01-Workspace_Setup
mkdir 02-Tiles
mkdir 03-Orthos
mkdir 04-Saved_Workspaces
mkdir 05-Backup
mkdir 06-Raw
mkdir 07-Excluded

mkdir ECW
mkdir FixPoints
mkdir ImageFrames
mkdir PCR
mkdir ProjectInfo
mkdir Seamlines
mkdir TrackingGrid
mkdir FixTo_Boundary

:NextItem
if "%blocks%" == "" pause & goto :EOF

set /A ItemCount+=1
for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ("%blocks%") do (
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\02-Tiles
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\03-Orthos
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\06-Raw
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\07-Excluded

    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\ECW
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\FixPoints
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\ImageFrames
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\PCR
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\ProjectInfo
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\Seamlines
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\TrackingGrid
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\FixTo_Boundary

    set "blocks=%%b"

    move /y ECW .\01-Workspace_Setup
    move /y FixPoints .\01-Workspace_Setup
    move /y ImageFrames .\01-Workspace_Setup
    move /y PCR .\01-Workspace_Setup
    move /y ProjectInfo .\01-Workspace_Setup
    move /y Seamlines .\01-Workspace_Setup
    move /y TrackingGrid .\01-Workspace_Setup
    move /y FixTo_Boundary .\01-Workspace_Setup

    move /y 01-Workspace_Setup .\%gsd%
    move /y 02-Tiles .\%gsd%
    move /y 03-Orthos .\%gsd%
    move /y 04-Saved_Workspaces .\%gsd%
    move /y 05-Backup .\%gsd%
    move /y 06-Raw .\%gsd%
    move /y 07-Excluded .\%gsd%
)
goto NextItem



echo Folder creation complete. Have a pleasant day!
pause
```

Based on the comments I have altered the code to be:

```
@echo off

rem Get User Input
set /p gsd= Enter the GSD of the project: 
set /p blocks= Enter the blocks you are prepping a drive for separated by commas (i.e. A,B,C,etc.): 

mkdir %gsd%

mkdir 01-Workspace_Setup
mkdir 02-Tiles
mkdir 03-Orthos
mkdir 04-Saved_Workspaces
mkdir 05-Backup
mkdir 06-Raw
mkdir 07-Excluded

mkdir ECW
mkdir FixPoints
mkdir ImageFrames
mkdir PCR
mkdir ProjectInfo
mkdir Seamlines
mkdir TrackingGrid
mkdir FixTo_Boundary

if %blocks% == "" pause & goto :EOF

for %%a in (%blocks%) do (
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\02-Tiles
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\03-Orthos
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\06-Raw
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\07-Excluded

    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\ECW
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\FixPoints
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\ImageFrames
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\PCR
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\ProjectInfo
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\Seamlines
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\TrackingGrid
    mkdir Block_%%a
    move /y Block_%%a .\FixTo_Boundary

)

move /y ECW .\01-Workspace_Setup
move /y FixPoints .\01-Workspace_Setup
move /y ImageFrames .\01-Workspace_Setup
move /y PCR .\01-Workspace_Setup
move /y ProjectInfo .\01-Workspace_Setup
move /y Seamlines .\01-Workspace_Setup
move /y TrackingGrid .\01-Workspace_Setup
move /y FixTo_Boundary .\01-Workspace_Setup

move /y 01-Workspace_Setup .\%gsd%
move /y 02-Tiles .\%gsd%
move /y 03-Orthos .\%gsd%
move /y 04-Saved_Workspaces .\%gsd%
move /y 05-Backup .\%gsd%
move /y 06-Raw .\%gsd%
move /y 07-Excluded .\%gsd%

echo Folder creation complete. Have a pleasant day!
pause
```

When run with one block, everything works it appears.  `Block_%%a` folders are nested where they should be and the structure looks fine.  When run with no variable or multiple variables (A,B,C), the thing blows up and doesn't function.  It will create all folders but the `Block_%%a` folders and not nest anything.  I tried to create it so it would just build the folders already nested but I couldn't figure out the proper syntax to do that.

Comment: IMO it doesn't make any sense to create new folders and then move them to other folders - instead create them directly in the destination. With extensions ebabled (default) md will also create intermediate folders in one step see `md /?`. Also without first CDing into `%gsd%` all the new folders are created in the current folder. You should [edit] your question to contain a tree of the desired structure - see `tree /?`

Comment: To process the variable %blocks% use a simple `for %%a in (%blocks%) do ...` not a `for /f`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong but access to the interpreter CMD will create the files with the above script, read the line, memorize the position, close the file/folder with  atribute a read-only and  what need to do change this by the Interpreter  attributes from read-only to archives

Answer (score 0):

The quotes are making the list appear to be one item.

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in ("%blocks%") do (
```

should be

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in (%blocks%) do (
```

As mentioned, you do not need a /F loop. You could:

```
for %%a in (%blocks%) do (
```

Comment: @NickGagne - Does that mean that the code is working?

Comment: I am having trouble getting the `for %%a in (%blocks%) do (` function to work properly.  It will function with one block, if I just enter A or whatever, but will not work when I provide no input for blocks or more than one (i.e. A,B,C).

Comment: If I enter more than one block, it will create all the top level and second level folders but none of the blocks folders and it won't nest them as I have it written.  They all remain top level